# How to count cardinity of 2 set AxB?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have question about cardinity of AxB . My question

Let A={0, a}, B={0, b}. Find the cardinality of the set P(A x B)

I think answer is 4 but 16 is answer and i dont know why ? Thank for your help

Comment: The number of elements in the power set of a set of $n$ elements is $2^n$. Here $n=4 \implies 2^n = 16$

Comment: The answer $16$ is only correct under the extra conditions $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$.

Comment: You counted the size of $A \times B$ rather than $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: So n = number element in A x number element in B ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $A$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements then $A\times B$ has $n\times m$ elements.

If $C$ has $k$ elements then $\wp(C)$ has $2^k$ elements.

Comment: Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

$$\#(A\times B)=\#A\times\#B$$

and

$$\#P(A)=2^{\#A}.$$